# Struts form and request attributes are null (Struts 1.3)

Tags: java, struts

I'm running into a trivial problem but haven't done Struts in the last 8 years :D...  Can someone point out what is wrong with my code? Is the submit ok? I just don't know why that my ProcessPaymentAction receives a request with null parameters and a form with null values...

Here's my struts-config.xml file...

```
    <action-mappings>
    <action path="/wpa"
        type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" name="wpaForm"
        scope="session" input="page.wpa" validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="page.success" />
    </action>

    <action path="/wpa2"
        type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" name="wpaForm"
        scope="session" input="page.wpa2" validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="page.success" />
    </action>
```

here is my initial action class that feeds the form...

```
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Entering WPADispatchAction");
    }

    WPAForm wpaForm = (WPAForm) form;

    StateHelper.initClientType(request, response);
    ClientTypeEnum clientType = StateHelper.retrieveClientType(request);

    String planType = request.getParameter(RequestParamEnum.PLANT_TYPE.getParamName());
    String province = request.getParameter(RequestParamEnum.PROVINCE.getParamName());
    String language = request.getParameter(RequestParamEnum.LANGUAGE.getParamName());
    String userType = request.getParameter(RequestParamEnum.USER_TYPE.getParamName());
    String isPayableByCreditCard = request.getParameter(RequestParamEnum.PAY_BY_CC_ALLOWED.getParamName());

    request.getSession().setAttribute("language", language);

    wpaForm.setCryptCode(MonerisConfigHelper.retrieveMonerisCryptCode());
    wpaForm.setMonerisUrl(MonerisConfigHelper.retrieveMonerisURL());
    addResponseUrlCookie(response, 
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(isPayableByCreditCard)){
        wpaForm.setProcessPaymentByCard(Boolean.valueOf(isPayableByCreditCard));
    } else {
        wpaForm.setProcessPaymentByCard(false);
    }
```

Here's the action called when the page is submitted...

```
    @Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse reponse) throws Exception {

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Entering ProcessPaymentAction");
    }

    WPAForm wpaForm = (WPAForm) form;

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    String sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");
    String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
    String policyID = request.getParameter("policyID");
```

and here, my form and all parameters are null...

This is the jsp submitting the form..

```
  <html:form action="/wpa2" styleId="wpaForm" method="post">
```

and the javascript function...

```
function submitForm() {

var theForm = document.getElementById("wpaForm");
if (planType == 'B') {
    theForm.action = "processhpcipayment.do";
} else if (planType == 'E') {
    theForm.action = "processmonthly.do";
}
document.getElementById("wpaForm").submit();
```

}

and my form...

```
public class WPAForm extends ActionForm {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7519298876451952530L;

private String policyID;

private String amount;

private String storeID;

public String getPolicyID() {
    return policyID;
}

public void setPolicyID(String policyID) {
    this.policyID = policyID;
}

public String getStoreID() {
    return storeID;
}

public void setStoreID(String storeID) {
    this.storeID = storeID;
}
public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

...

Comment: Completely unrelated, but one of the first things `log.debug` does is a call to `isDebugEnabled`. The only benefit of wrapping `log.debug` calls in an `enabled` wrapper is if the log statement is complex enough that it should be skipped. For a non-constructed log statement, e.g., your strings, it's just useless noise.

Comment: Need to see, at least, the form declaration, and the action config that you're actually submitting to.

Comment: I thought I had put everything... added my form.

Comment: Do you see how you're submitting to an entirely different action because you change the action via JavaScript? We need the declaration of those actions.

Comment: The form has not any field, even if it has it should be populated the action form  because Struts 1.3 support the concept of action form bean. It should be properly configured to be working, but posted information is not enough to see how it could be involved. Different objects have different functionality, if the the code is too old then it's useless to refactor it using Struts 1.3 but better to rewrite it from scratch using Struts 2.